# Where can I set the default terminal emulator?

Tags: command-line, configuration, default

GNOME Terminal shows up in several places:

- launchers which start terminal commands
- the Launch Terminal keyboard shortcut
- the menu items added by nautilus-open-terminal

Does each of these explicitly specify GNOME Terminal, or is there some centralized setting they reference?

I have checked for:

- A setting in **System Settings ▸ System Info ▸ Default Applications**
- An analog of [`select-editor`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/select-editor.1.html) or [`sensible-editor`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/sensible-editor.1.html)
- An environment variable containing `gnome-terminal`. This one actually looks hopeful:

  ```
  $ env | grep gnome-terminal
  COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
  ```

  but I'm not sure where to go with it.

If such a setting exists, my goal is to change it to use a different terminal emulator by default.