# Setting nautilus-open-terminal to launch Terminator rather than gnome-terminal

Tags: nautilus, gnome-terminal, terminator

The `nautilus-open-terminal` package adds a menu/right-click option to open a terminal in the current directory.

I want to change this from opening `gnome-terminal` to opening `terminator`. [There is some advice on changing the default terminal emulator here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1635122), however these instructions do not appear to be valid any more, and I can't find any place in the system settings where the default emulator can be changed.

I also tried:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

choosing

```
* 0            /usr/bin/terminator               50        auto mode
```

But this does not appear to have any effect. Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: [Here's a question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72517/where-can-i-set-the-default-terminal-emulator) about setting the default terminal emulator.

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it doesn't work. In fact the "Open in Terminal" command does nothing now

Comment: Tested this just now to see how was it working for terminator, with terminator you need to set up the full path to the program, after that it will work like a charm by pressing ctrl+alt+t or when you have a program calling the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Everything you've described works fine, however I can't get `nautilus-open-terminal` working with Terminator, which is really my original question. If you or anyone has any insights into how I can make this work I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Ubuntu 13.04:** (in case you came here via google)

You can't change the terminal app used anymore.

*Details*:
`nautilus-open-terminal` uses `GAppInfo` to launch the terminal process, which uses a hard coded list of terminal emulators: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/main/gio/gdesktopappinfo.c#L2581

*Solution:*

1. Remove gnome-terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal
   ```
2. Symlink terminator to gnome-terminal:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/terminator /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
   ```

Comment: See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=743626 --- I think this is a bug.

Comment: Really it is https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627943 --- here since 2010. Ok.

Comment: For Ubuntu Mate, do: `sudo apt-get remove mate-terminal` followed by `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/terminator /usr/bin/mate-terminal`.

Comment: This does not work in 16.04. I can launch `gnome-terminal` from the command line, but Nautilus's "Open in Terminal" option does nothing.

Comment: On 16.04, I use https://gist.github.com/randy3k/c7f69adc2754f4b2bff361fbfd0fdc5d to open `io.elementary.terminal`, I guess you just have to copy it to `/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions` and patch it for `terminator`.

Comment: As @Cerin said, doesn't work in 16.04, or 17.10, or Manjaro Gnome, openSUSE Gnome, or Solus Gnome. Basically, any Gnome distro it seems using Gnome 3.26.x

Comment: This should be the related GitLab issue. Gnome seems to be migrating away from Bugzilla. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/issues/338 Go and upvote this.

Comment: I also had to symlink `/usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server` in order for it to work.

Comment: issue https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/338 is now closed and "will be in the 2.76.0 release in <6 months’ time."

Comment: On 23.04, clicking "Open in terminal" will fail with "org.gnome.Nautilus[35888]: Error creating terminal: The name org.gnome.Terminal was not provided by any .service files" in the syslog.

Answer (score 45):

### Install [nautilus-actions](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/filemanager-actions) (AKA filemanager-actions)

We may define our own right-click context menu items with **nautilus-actions**.

- Run the *Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool* either from the Dash, or from a terminal with

  ```
  nautilus-actions-config-tool
  ```

  [image: screenshot]
- In the *Action* tab give your action a sensible label, e.g. *"Open in Terminator"* and choose to display this in the selection or the context menu.
- Next open the *Command* tab to enter the commands to run

  [image: screenshot]
- Give in the full path to your command (`/usr/bin/terminator`) and program options (`--working-directory=%d/%b`) for opening the current path in Terminator.
- After **logging out and in again** (or just **restarting nautilus** with `nautilus -q`) the right click context menu below will be displayed:

  [image: screenshot]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the detailed writeup! I will try this tomorrow when I get to the office and report back.

Comment: Great solution. One thing: It's not really necessary to log out/in, restarting nautilus with `nautilus -q` is sufficient. I just proposed an edit for that.

Comment: Nautilus-Actions can't go to relative symlinks paths, it uses absolute dispatchers, but open-in-terminal plugin opens relative paths.

Comment: wow thank you so much I didn't know that application existed :)

Comment: if you don't want `Open in Terminator` to be in submenu, in Nautilus-Actions, go to Edit > Preferences > Disable "Create a root 'Nautilus-Actions' menu"

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package nautilus-actions-config-tool`

Comment: @Cerin: `/usr/bin/nautilus-actions-config-tool` not installed?

Comment: The project seems to be archived and the package is no longer available in the apt repositories (tested on Pop!_OS 22.04)

Answer (score 24):

To configure the default terminal in gnome you need to install dconf-tools (sudo apt-get install dconf-tools).

After that you can use dconf-editor or gsettings to set your favorite terminal emulator. This guide uses `gsettings`.

After installing `terminator` type this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator
```

Set the `exec-args` for the terminal you need, in your case `-x` to execute the rest of the necessary arguments of `nautilus-open-terminal`.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"
```

After this terminator will be your default terminal emulator, when `nautilus-open-terminal` calls the default terminal it should open `terminator` instead of `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: The arguments are required. Have edited and accepted.

Comment: What arguments are you using with `terminator`, if its useful I will edit the answer and add that information.

Comment: it's `org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg '-x'` as in my edit.

Comment: But the key point is it's already set correctly by default - what works for `gnome-terminal` works for `terminator`.

Comment: Ok, then I will leave it like this, just added an extra point to make clear that nautilus-open-terminal will call the default and that will then be terminator and not gnome-terminal.

Comment: Hang on, I think there was a miscommunication. The default setting with `gnome-terminal` is `exec-arg "-x"` and `terminator` *also* requires this argument to work with `nautilus-open-terminal`. If you set `exec-arg ""` then nothing happens when you use `nautilus-open-terminal` with either `gnome-terminal` or `terminator.` In summary what you have on there at the moment is incorrect

Comment: On 13.04, it would be... `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator` and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"`

Comment: @nopacus this does not seem to work anymore, I still get the "normal" terminal. Maybe because of https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=159139

Comment: Just tested my instructions on 13.04, they work and are valid, no modifications on the commands

Comment: @BrunoPereira are you sure? I just followed these instructions, and for me, the normal terminal appears.

Comment: @Cristoph, I filed https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=743626

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04...

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: On Ubuntu 23.10 you can edit this with dconf `/org/gnome/desktop/applications/terminal/exec` and `/org/gnome/desktop/applications/terminal/exec-arg`. So for Guake terminal I used `guake` and `` values. This means `Ctrl+T` now opens guake, however, Nautilus still opens the original terminal.

Answer (score 15):

### Update for Ubuntu 19.04 and 20.04

I agree with [this answer by Takkat](https://askubuntu.com/a/76946/1044065) which suggests to install **nautilus-configuration-tool** to solve this, but since Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) therefore also for Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) this package is called **[filemanager-actions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=filemanager-actions)**. I know thanks to [the answer by N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138682/1044065).
So if you are getting this error: `E: Unable to locate package nautilus-actions-config-tool`
Use these commands:

```
sudo apt install filemanager-actions  # To install
fma-config-tool  # To run the configuration tool
```

and follow the instructions in [the answer by N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138682/1044065).

If you want your action to appear in the **top level of the context menu**, go to `Edit > Preferences > Runtime Preferences` and uncheck the `Create a root 'FileManager-Actions' menu` (based on the comment from [stefg-bz](https://askubuntu.com/users/403254/stefg-bz)).

---

### Offtopic but related (Yakuake terminal)

In case you found this answer because you are trying to achieve the same thing as the OP asked, but with **Yakuake terminal**, use the script `yakuake-session` from [this repo](https://github.com/aplatanado/yakuake-session) and set the command of your action in the FileManager-Actions Configuration Tool like this:

```
Path: /usr/bin/yakuake-session
Parameters: --workdir=%d/%b
Working directory: %d
```

I also had to do `sudo apt install qdbus-qt5` in order to make it work otherwise I was getting `yakuake-session: error: cannot connect to Yakuake`.

*I am unable to comment so I add a new answer (I do not understand this rule tbh)*

Comment: Yet another update will be needed for Ubuntu 19.04 and higher. File-manager-actions is no more.

Answer (score 11):

### For Ubuntu 22.04 and above

#### Tell gnome-terminal to open your preferred terminal

A somewhat hacky workaround, but it works for me:

1. Open gnome-terminal and navigate to Preferences > (your profile) > Command
2. Check "Run custom command instead of my shell" and add the command for your preferred terminal emulator
3. Under "Preserve working directory" select "Always"

**Warning:** this will cause gnome-terminal to close immediately after startup. I recommend testing with "When command exits" set to "Hold the terminal open" to make sure everything works as expected.

**Reverting:** run `gnome-terminal --preferences` from another terminal to open just the preferences window, and uncheck "Run custom command instead of my shell".

[image]

Comment: Sure, it's somewhat "hacky" but IMO _way_ easier (and far less invasive) than having to install  other software packages and tweak numerous things.  Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for :) I wish I could upvote twice...

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and also the only one that works for me on Ubuntu 22.04.1. None of the other things like filemanager-actions seem available anymore. Thank you so much

Comment: I can't get this to work without it leaving the gnome-terminal window open for some reason on latest 22.04 - teminator opens and gnome-terminal stays open, and if I close gnome-terminal it kills terminator.

Comment: OK I got it working by wrapping terminator in a bash call - `/bin/bash  -c "/usr/bin/terminator"`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I wan't able to solve the problem. Instead I installed `nautilus-terminal` which embeds your terminal into nautilus! Which is absolutely great.

### Install nautilus-terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flozz/nautilus-terminal
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nautilus-terminal
nautilus -q
```

[image]

You can also configure it via dconf editor.
More info in [this link](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/09/get-terminal-embedded-in-nautilus-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but since I landed here while trying to do the same thing, [here's my take for future visits](http://www.alvaroferran.com/blog/open-nautilus-with-terminator).

I tried all the previous suggestions and failed, so instead I came up with this workaround (not a perfect answer, but can still be useful I guess).

Create a change_terminal.sh file

```
# Open a new terminator window in a detached tmux session so it remains open
cmd="terminator --working-directory=$PWD"
tmux new-session -d
tmux send-keys "$cmd" C-m
tmux dettach
# Close active window (gnome-terminal since the new one hasn't loaded yet)
xdotool key --clearmodifiers Ctrl+Shift+Q key --clearmodifiers KP_Enter
```

and give it execution rights:

```
chmod +x change_terminal.sh
```

Create the following alias:

```
alias ct="path/to/change_terminal.sh"
```

Now you just open a default terminal from nautilus in the desired location and type 'ct' to close it and open a terminator terminal in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer works for Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Download and install the most recent deb package:
https://github.com/bassmanitram/actions-for-nautilus/tree/main/dist

Open the application *Actions For Nautilus configuration*.

In the top left, add an action as shown:
[Open in Terminator Menu option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKueM.png)

You should also only allow *directory* in the *File types* section. Save the action then Restart nautilus (file manager). This will give you the desired option in the menu. If you don't want the original *Open in Terminal* option, then you can just uninstall gnome-terminal with `sudo apt remove gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score -1):

I've created this alias:

```bsh
alias tt='terminator & disown & exit'
```

Now when I click on the option 'open in terminal', I just type 'tt' in the opened terminal and it switches to terminator, in the same location.

I wanted something simpler but, as you can see from the previous answers there is no such thing (until now) as a nautilus-tweaker or a tool to personalize it's behaviour.