# How do I set the default terminal in GNOME?

Tags: gnome

I want to change the default terminal in the GNOME desktop environment to `lilyterm`. Here are the instructions that I've found on the internet:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec lilyterm
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg ""
```

But when I'm pressing the shortcut that should run the default terminal, I'm getting:

> Windows manager warning: Error on terminal command"(null)". Terminal
> command is not defined.

Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried changing it via the Terminal command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

I guess this does not help if the GNOME shortcut is set specifically to `gnome-terminal` instead of `x-terminal-emulator`.

Answer (score 10):

Most of the answers here are outdated for today's Gnome software. For Gnome 3.36 there's no easy workaround. The problem lies in the fact that most Gnome software is based on Gio which it decides what terminal emulator to use eventually. Quoting [a Gnome developer from gitlab.gnome.org](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1559#note_592512):

> The decision which terminal is going to be used by gnome-shell when starting apps that specify that they run in a terminal is made by glib and not gnome-shell and currently in glib there is a hardcoded list of terminals that is being tried).

Hence, looking e.g at Gio's (version 2.76.2) [code responsible for this behavior](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/2.76.2/gio/gdesktopappinfo.c?ref_type=tags#L2701-2713), we can see that Gio has hard coded the tests for several specific terminal emulators' executables search in `$PATH`. `xdg-terminal-exec` is tested there first and other terminal emulators are tested further. If `xdg-terminal-exec` is found in your `$PATH`, it will be used and there's nothing one can do, besides altering the programs in your `$PATH`:

```
# ln -s /usr/bin/lilyterm /usr/bin/xdg-terminal-exec
```

This also means that the most widely solution to this problem, using `gsettings`, doesn't work (also proposed here: [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/724852/390963), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/348796/135796), [3](https://askubuntu.com/a/1096331/390963), [4](https://askubuntu.com/a/1194659/390963), [5](https://askubuntu.com/a/76747/390963)).

Comment: As of gnome 3.36.8 (Ubuntu 20.04.8) this solution doesnt work either. Nautilus keeps opening gnome-terminal. I tried update-alternatives + creating a symlink to the terminal I want to launch when right-clicking -> Open In Terminal. update-alternatives only changes the behavior of Ctrl-Alt-T. That really sucks.

Comment: Here on NixOS, with gnome 41.2, and nautilus 41.1, I don't even see anymore the "open terminal" button.

Comment: @DanielBişar, @DoronBehar For Nautilus, you will have to uninstall `nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal` plugin, and then instead install the [`nautilus-open-any-terminal`](https://github.com/Stunkymonkey/nautilus-open-any-terminal) plugin.

Comment: @DoronBehar apparently, there has been some development in this area, and (per your link to the bugzilla) GNOME will support the `xdg-terminal-exec` utility going forward. May be interesting to revise your answer in a couple of months, if `xdg-terminal-exec` should become part of the freedesktop standard. +1 for the comprehensive (and most up to date) answer though

Comment: Thanks for noticing @Fynn. I update the links and I updated the `ln` command to use `xdg-terminal-exec`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options:

- Try with:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'lilyterm'
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg '-x'
  ```

  Note: You need to log out and log in again (tested succesfully on GNOME on Ubuntu 13.04).
- Another possibility is to go to *Shortcuts* in GNOME Settings and add a new one with `lilyterm` as command, and set it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or anything else you prefer.
- Another way is to replace `gnome-terminal` with a symlink that points to `lilyterm` - but you don't want to do that.

Comment: Still equal error message.

Comment: I modified the answer, please check this.

Comment: Nothing changes :(. In my opinion, such error message indicates, that `desktop.default-applications.terminal` and `Default Terminal` in shortcut settings is different things.

Comment: Have tou tried to logout-login after changing the settings? I think that gconf should be updated with this new gsettings configurations.

Comment: @dadexix86less yes, I have.

Comment: That's interesting. As said here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Default_terminal it seems that these settings are just for nautilus-open-terminal (can you check that there it works?) I added a couple of possible workarounds to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just accidentally bumped into this question and this what worked for me:

1. Check which terminal is left in your system. I had already removed all "terminal apps" such as xterm etc and chose `rxvt-unicode` as default terminal.
2. Then go to Settings → *Keyboard Shortcuts* and create a custom shortcut. It will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should open the add/edit users dialogue and see if you can change the default terminal there.

Updated: **Users & Groups (as admin) > Select User > Advanced Settings > Advanced > Shell**

There is a drop down menu, but you can also type out /path/to/your/shell.

Comment: This is talking about terminal emulators, not shells.