# How change default terminal in "open in terminal" in GIO

Tags: terminator, ubuntu-mate

I want to use `terminator` instead of default terminal in `Ubuntu mate`. I changed it in `dconf Editor` but the entry is DEPRECATED because managed by GIO.

Comment: What  is `GIO` ?  The typical way to changing the best way to change terminal is through `gsettings` .   Shouldn't be any different in `Mate`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy https://docs.gtk.org/gio/index.html ?

Answer (score 3):

Right, thank you

It was done with gsettings

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"
```

Comment: This is the same setting, whether edited by `dconf` Editor or by `gsettings`. It is DEPRECATED as mentioned in the question.