# How to change the default terminal for "open in terminal"?

Tags: command-line, guake

I have installed the guake in my ubuntu 18.04 . According to this question [How change default terminal in “open in terminal” in GIO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724810/how-change-default-terminal-in-open-in-terminal-in-gio), I followed it and set

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/guake 
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"
```

After that, guake can be opened by ctrl+w successfully. But if I open any file and try to "open in terminal", it dosen't work, the old terminal (the orgin terminal of gnome) will be opened.