# Replace Tilix as the default terminal emulator in ubuntu-budgie-desktop running on ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, budgie

I've recently installed ubuntu-budgie-desktop on ubuntu18.04 and while I like most of the features, I'm annoyed with the Tilix terminal emulator. So I wish to change it back to gnome-terminal-emulator. But I've set it on `update-alternatives config x-terminal-emulator` but still when I press `CTRL`+`ALT`+`T` Tilix comes up.

What should I do?

Comment: What happens if you run `x-terminal-emulator`?

Comment: @vanadium when I run `x-terminal-emulator` in a terminal window it opens gnome-terminal-emulator. But when I press `CTRL+ALT+T` it still opens up Tilix

Comment: What is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec`? That also should yield `x-terminal-emulator`.

Comment: @vanadium it does

Comment: it should have but it didn't thus I had to do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally solved it, the issue arises b/c of `org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal` keeping the value tilix instead of changing to gnome-terminal.
I used `dconf-editor`, searched for terminal and finally found it and then changed the `Custom value` value to `gnome-terminal`

Comment: Seems this has been updated, and dconf-editor says this changed in "GIO". Followed the instructions here to change it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/724810/how-change-default-terminal-in-open-in-terminal-in-gio