# How to change my default terminal to GNOME Terminal rather than Terminator?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I was wondering how I can go back to using the GNOME Terminal as my default terminal in Ubuntu rather than having Terminator as my default. Also, I do not want to uninstall Terminator, I just don't want to have it as my default one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1. **Updating the alternatives:** For this run

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
   ```

   and select the number corresponding to `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper`. This will set GNOME terminal as the default entry under `x-terminal-emulator`. But this might change if some other new terminal is installed in future since that installation may edit default value for `x-terminal-emulator`.
2. **Setting GNOME terminal as default**: For this you can run

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'gnome-terminal'
   ```

Comment: doesn't that set the terminator to the default terminal?

Comment: Thank you for notifying. Corrected the command. I'll just expand that in a moment to add more details.

Comment: I find this answer to be most effective (see my comment underneath it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336587/114401), in conjunction with this answer also (see my comment underneath it too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582462/114401).

Answer (score 0):

Just type the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

It will show several terminal applications that are installed on your system. Type the number corresponding to the terminal you wish.

Now, the selected terminal is the default terminal and will open when you press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.