# How to set GNOME Console as default Terminal app?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, default-programs

As of the moment writing this, `gnome-terminal` is the default terminal app in GNOME. However, considering  development progress of the new app called `gnome-console` you may want to use it as the default terminal app and hence to be able to open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

In recent versions of GNOME, changing keyboard shortcuts is much easier than before under **Keyboard** section of **Settings**. But the question is what the command is to open Console – no, it’s not `gnome-console`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Shortcut key

It seems so easy if you know the command. You will open **Settings** > **Keyboard** > **View and Customize Shortcuts** in *Keyboard Shortcuts* section, then you will search for *Terminal* and replace the command.

After months of searching the internet and failing to find the command, I finally could find it out on the package file list: `kgx` – That’s it!

[image: Terminal Keyboard Shortcut]

Next time you press Ctrl+Alt+T, it will open GNOME Console for you.

### 2. Make it default

Apparantly it’s not easy to use an app other than `gnome-terminal` as the default one on GNOME, but there’s a neat workaround as mentioned in an answer to a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1262935/89497):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/kgx /usr/local/bin/gnome-terminal
```

With this symbolic link every time the OS wants to call up Terminal, it will open GNOME Console instead.

Comment: any reason why the shortcut is not set as default (like on all other major distros)?