# Ubuntu 13.04: Set Terminator as default terminal emulator with nautilus "open terminal"

Tags: nautilus, 13.04, terminator

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 a few days ago.
With Ubuntu 12.10 I had set the default terminal with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"
```

I had set it with `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` too.

But none of these options work on Ubuntu 13.04.

How can I set Terminator as default terminal emulator with nautilus "*open terminal*"?

**This isn't a duplicate. As I've said: the solutions in [How can I set default terminal used in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used) doesn't work on Ubuntu 13.04 with nautilus "open terminal".

My question is: "Set Terminator as default terminal emulator WITH NAUTILUS "OPEN TERMINAL" on Ubuntu 13.04"**

Comment: Next time please mention what you've looked at already. It would help a lot.

Comment: Next time please read better the entire question. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to add an 'Open in Terminator' option:

1. Install 'Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool'

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
   ```
2. In 'Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool', add a new rule with the following (as a guidance):

   - In the Actions tab, tick both boxes and select an appropriate name (e.g. Open in Terminator):

     [image: Action (tab)]
   - In the Command tab, set:

     - Path: terminator
     - Parameters: --working-directory=%f

     [image: Command (tab)]
   - In the Mimetypes tab, set:

     - Mimetype filter: inode/directory

   [image: Mimetypes (tab)]

   - Go to File > Save to save the rule and you're all set.
3. I recommend that you also change the preferences in Nautious-Actions Configuration Tool to get rid of the two level context menu by unticking the following in Edit > Preferences:

   - (untick) Create a root 'Nautilus-Actions' menu
   - (untick) Add an 'About Nautious-Actions'  item in the Nautilus context menus

   [image: Preferences]
4. Log out and Log in again.

Now you're all set and should see a 'Open in Terminator' option if you right-click in Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install terminator && sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal && sudo ln /usr/bin/terminator /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

Comment: This "fix" is a bit sloppy.

Comment: While I agree the symlink way is sloppy, it's what most people will resort to since the "correct" way is ridiculously unintuitive. The desktop needs to provide a better way of handling this, then "sloppy methods" will naturally go away.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a bit of a 'hack', but it's less painful than the one provided by Germano, and allows you to still use gnome-terminal if you need to by referring to it with a full pathname (i.e. `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` instead of just `gnome-terminal`).

Make sure your ~/.bashrc file contains the following somewhere in it:

```
if [ -d ~/bin ]; then
    export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
fi
```

Then run the following in a shell:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/terminator ~/bin/gnome-terminal
```

**Finally, log-out, and back in to your Ubuntu account.**

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Just saw this meaning it maybe does not work with 13.04 after all. Still, it is something I would try (I'm on 12.04 LTS btw): 
[Setting nautilus-open-terminal to launch Terminator rather than gnome-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76712/setting-nautilus-open-terminal-to-launch-terminator-rather-than-gnome-terminal?rq=1)

**Original Message:**

It may be too late, but since I was looking for a solution to the same thing but for konsole...

If you install `dconf-editor` you can (very similar to the gsettings commands) set the terminal you want to have opened by opening dconf-editor and setting:

```
org->gnome->desktop->applications->terminal->exec = terminator
org->gnome->desktop->applications->terminal->exec-arg = -x
```

Afterwards you can quit and re-initialise nautilus with `nautilus -q` (may take two executions for the following to appear)

```
$ /usr/bin/nautilus -q
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
Initializing nautilus-open-terminal extension
Shutting down nautilus-open-terminal extension
Shutting down nautilus-gdu extension
```

It's also now possible to debug nautilus from the command line with:

```
$ /usr/bin/nautilus
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
Initializing nautilus-open-terminal extension
...
...
```

Any problems when calling 'Open in Terminal' will be logged here.

**NOTE:** this was only possible directly after calling with the `-q` flag. Otherwise calling nautilus simply opens the application and returns to the shell without logging.

My problem, if it interests anyone, was that the `-x` arg doesn't work with konsole, so I changed it to `--new-tab -e` because I didn't want a new Konsole window opening up everytime.

Hopes it helps someone.