# Is filemanager-actions working with 19.04?

Tags: nautilus, 19.04

I installed `filemanager-actions` from Ubuntu software, but cannot succeed to create a new entry in the file manager context menu :

I installed `gnome-search-tool`, and want to add it on a right click on a folder in `nautilus`.

So I create a new action in `filemanager-actions`, on the *Action* tab I enter "`Search...`" for the *label*, and in the *Command* tab, I enter "`gnome-search-tool`" in the path field, plus "`--path="%d"`" in the *parameter* field.

But nothing appears in `nautilus` ; after restart or reboot still nothing.

Am I missing something, or is it just not working ? 
Is there a way to achieve that ? Idea is to be able to search within files for some keywords in a specific folder/subfolders.
Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The FMA is installable from *universe* pocket [since Ubuntu 19.04 (disco dingo, now EOL)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=filemanager-actions) and then on supported 20.04 LTS (focal fossa) with

```
sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions
```

Then you need to run `fma-config-tool` (FileManager-Actions Configuration Tool) and make sure that you have checked checkboxes

> **Nautilus Item**
> [v] Display item in selection context menu
> [v] Display item in location context menu
> [image: fma]

and have saved settings.

The documentation is available from official help which is available from `fma-config-tool` with <kbd>F1</kbd> (or with `yelp ghelp:fma-config-tool`).

Then you need to install Nautilus Actions package with

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

then restart Nautilus with `nautilus -q`.

The corresponding menu item will be shown in the right mouse click menus:

> [image: Nautilus with fma]

---

Note: the actions set in `fma-config-tool` will be shown in Caja in Nemo too. In these cases we need to install corresponding `caja-actions` and/or `nemo-extension-fma` packages.

Comment: Thank you, much better like this. Still two remarks : I was expecting the menu to appear at first level, not below "FileManager-Actions actions", and second the search tool opens in the current directory, not the folder I clicked on (for example I have nautilus in /home/user, I right click on /home/user/folder1 and select my action : the search tool opens with /home/user as the folder to search in).

Comment: It seems that it works this way. I have tested FMA with simple `zenity` example. You can read some official documentation which is available from `fma-config-tool` (or with `yelp ghelp:fma-config-tool`). I think that we have solved original problem.

Comment: @pled for items to appear at top level in the context menu, not under "FileManager-Actions actions", you have to uncheck the option in `fma-config-tool` Edit > Preferences > Runtime Preferences > "Create a root 'FileManager-Actions' menu"

Comment: @stefg-bz : Thanks, much better like this !

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04, august 2020

Comment: After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.10, both `filemanager-actions` and `nautilus-actions` packages have been removed and I cannot reinstall them anymore via `apt`. Could you help me with this issue? Thanks

Comment: Simple ignore this GNOME dead-stuff, use MATE with Caja and [`caja-actions`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/caja-actions) instead.

Comment: I'm getting this error on Ubuntu 22: 

```
E: Unable to locate package filemanager-actions

```

Answer (score 4):

I am writing this answer because I am not eligible to comment here, only a small correction in @N0rbert answer and that is to install nautilus-actions we have to use the command `sudo apt install nautilus-extension-fma` in ubuntu 20.04 release.
the rest of the answer would be same.