# nautilus-like scripts with ubuntu budgie?

Tags: scripts, ubuntu-budgie

I'd like to have the same sort of script possibility (right click) with the budgie default file manager (nemo) as I use to have with Nautilus using the classical Ubuntu (both 20.04.1).

Comment: Please provide the application and package name of the "budgie default file manager".

Comment: nano is not the file manager. It is NEMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the FileManager Actions packages for Nemo by

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-extension-fma filemanager-actions
```

And then configure actions as shown in [linked answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138682/66509).

Comment: Thank you. The link shows how to configure Nautilus  but not Nemo. Or I have missed something ?

Comment: FMA is universal, should work with Nemo too.

Comment: Can't find Nemo in FMA. But never mind it works miraculously after the installation of the package you've said. Thank you.