# Change terminal opened by "open in terminal" in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, settings, terminator

what I've tried:
set my default terminal to terminator using
`sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`
and
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator`
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"`
but no dice, looked through the preferences menu and didn't see any options to change the programs opened by the context menu. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [Setting nautilus-open-terminal to launch Terminator rather than gnome-terminal - Update for Ubuntu 19.04 and 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257070/178692)