# Change default terminal with right-click option "Open in Terminal" in file manager

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, konsole

I have installed Konsole on Ubuntu 20.04.2 and I want to set it as the default terminal emulator for which I have run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`.

When I go to the file manager and right-click in a folder and select "Open in Terminal" it runs the Gnome terminal emulator instead. How can I have Ubuntu select Konsole for this action?

Comment: Are you using the nautilus file manager? if so you may find this related question helpful: [Setting nautilus-open-terminal to launch Terminator rather than gnome-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257070/178692)

Comment: I had to remove nautilus to get rid of tracker, which ruined my desktop. I can live with all that. I use krusader for the file manager, and konsole for terminal... krusader has right click open with and also set as default. also F9 will open a terminal in current directory, it opens in konsole window for me (not sure if I had to set that or not)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many other questions on this topic, but solutions that once worked continuously break with newer nautilus versions. If I answer there, the answer is buried under a lot of very good answers, that currently don't work anymore. Hence, I answer here.

Currently, your best bet will be to use a nautilus python extension, [nautilus-open-any-terminal](https://github.com/Stunkymonkey/nautilus-open-any-terminal). It allows to implement a right-click menu to nautilus that launches the terminal of your choice (actually, one of the "supported terminals", but konsole is in the list) in the current folder.

You should install `python-nautilus`, or `python3-nautilus` depending on your version of Ubuntu. Then the extension can be installed with `pip`, which you also will need to install first.

You will want to remove the now redundant "native" "Open in Terminal" menu entry: do this by removing `nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 23.10 this worked for me only partially. I filed an issue here https://github.com/Stunkymonkey/nautilus-open-any-terminal/issues/115.