# Change terminal-emulator in ubuntu default filemanager

Tags: command-line, filemanager

in the Ubuntu default file manager when right-clicking there is an option to
[Open in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zK2L.png).

How can I change the terminal-emulator for the "Open in Terminal" option? I have changed my terminal emulator with the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

But it did not change for the "Open in Terminal" option.

Answer (score 2):

The option to open a terminal by right-clicking a file in nautilus is provided by a nautilus extension. That extension, unfortunately, is hard coded to work with `gnome-terminal`.

You can install an extension, [`nautilus-open-any-terminal`](https://github.com/Stunkymonkey/nautilus-open-any-terminal), that allows to select a terminal of choice to be used for the "Open terminal here" option. As a very valuable added bonus, it also allows you to set a shortcut key to open a terminal in the current directory. Yes, you may feel that I use the extension myself, even if it is for `gnome-terminal`.

**Removing the default extension**

Remove the default extension with the command:

```
sudo apt remove nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
```

This is the name as of Ubuntu 21.10. In older versions, the package was named `nautilus-open-terminal`.

**Installing the python extension gnome-open-terminal**

Install the dependency:

```
sudo apt install python-nautilus
```

Then install the extension

```
pip3 install --user nautilus-open-any-terminal
```

Then run the following command to allow configuring the extension using `dconf`:

```
glib-compile-schemas ~/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

**Configuring**

Set your preferred terminal using a command like the following (example for `alacritty`, see on the extension's website for the list of supported terminals):

```
gsettings set com.github.stunkymonkey.nautilus-open-any-terminal terminal alacritty
```

To set the shortcut key for opening the terminal:

```
gsettings set com.github.stunkymonkey.nautilus-open-any-terminal keybindings '<Ctrl><Alt>t'
```

If your terminal supports tabs, and you want the new terminal opened as a new tab instead of as a new window:

```
gsettings set com.github.stunkymonkey.nautilus-open-any-terminal new-tab true
```

Comment: can you add mutilple terminal entries in context menu using this above method. like for backup situation dafault terminal . because i added the terminator terminal and it replaced the default terminal. can they both live side by side.

Comment: @tikendraw Ik you keep the default extension, the entry for the default terminal emulator also will be there.

Comment: hey, I don't have `~/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` in my newly installed ubuntu.  getting this. error  ` glib-compile-schemas ~/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
Error opening directory “/home/t/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/”: No such file or directory
` Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your file browser configuration to point at new terminal emulator.

For Ubuntu default Nautilus you could see several options [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76712/setting-nautilus-open-terminal-to-launch-terminator-rather-than-gnome-terminal).

Comment: I guess you did not test any of these options yourself.